# Keep multiple loading states after calling graphql mutation many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm using react and react apollo in my application and have a question.
I have a page that contains list of users. Every item contains "+" button. When I click on item I want to display spinner until the mutation will finished.

Could you suggest me better solution for keeping `loading` for each mutation call?
Now I just store it into array, but I think it can be solved better

Comment: You can store this state in each item individually.

Comment: Do you mean to store this `loading` as a separate variable, not related to `loading` mutation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the relation between one `loading` process and the corresponding `user` item.

I suggest (without knowing your requirements) to have a `loadings` array, where you add a `loading item` containing the `user id` onClick, and remove the `loading item` when done. A `loading item` may also contain other info if necessary.

You also probably need to store the relation between the (probably asynchronous) `process` and the `loading item` (or the `user item`), so you know *which* `loading item` has finished.

You might do that by

1. receiving a `process id` from the `process` when you invoke it, and store that id inside the `loading item` together with the `user item id`,
2. or you might store the `loading id` as a closure when you invoke the `process`, and remove the corresponding `loading item`, e.g. inside a `.then((xyz)=>{... removeLoading(processId) ...})`.